# What exactly is an OutputIterator and how to build one for use with CGAL Kd_tree::search?

Tags: c++, class, iterator, kdtree, cgal

I'm using CGAL's Kd-tree implementation along with Fuzzy spheres as query objects to get the points enclosed in a sphere of radius `r_max` centered at a point. Here is this minimal working example:

```
    #include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
    #include <CGAL/Kd_tree.h>
    #include <CGAL/Search_traits_2.h>
    #include <CGAL/Fuzzy_sphere.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>  K;
    typedef K::Point_2                      Point;
    typedef CGAL::Search_traits_2<K>        TreeTraits;
    typedef CGAL::Kd_tree<TreeTraits>       Kd_tree;
    typedef Kd_tree::Tree                   Tree;
    typedef CGAL::Fuzzy_sphere<TreeTraits>  Sphere;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        double r_max;
        Tree tree;

        /* ... fill the tree with points, set the value of r_max ...*/

        // Report indices for the neighbors within a sphere
        unsigned int   idc_query = tree.size()/2;           // test index
        Tree::iterator kti       = idc_query + tree.begin();                                                                                
        Sphere s_query(*kti, r_max);                            

        // Print points
        tree.search(std::ostream_iterator<Point>(std::cout, "\n"), s_query);

        return 0;
    }
```

I took and adapted the line below the comment "Print points" from the nearest_neighbor_searching.cpp file under the Spatial_searching folder of CGAL's examples (my version is 3.9).

The question is: Is there a way for me to set a different `OutputIterator` (rather than `std::ostream_iterator`) that stores a pointer/iterator/handle to the points resulting from the search in a container of sorts, **instead** of having the points' coordinates printed to the standard output? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the C++ standard library, there are five kinds of iterators:

- Input iterator
- Output iterator
- Forward iterator
- Bidirectional iterator
- Random access iterator

For more information, see [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/)

In your case, you need an **Output iterator**, ie., an object `it` that can be incremented (`++it`) and de-referenced (`*it`) to get a non-const reference, that can be written to.

You can create an output iterator that inserts all items written to it at the end of a container using [`std::back_inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<Point> points;
tree.search(std::back_inserter(points), s_query);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and successful answer! While your suggestion worked straight away, making me overcome the biggest stumbling block, I would like to know if instead of the points themselves, I could save pointers to the points.

Comment: @LuisE.: I don't think you get the pointers, since `Tree::search()` seems to pass the points by value to the iterator.

Comment: Yes, I was checking the code and there seems to be no hope with `Tree::search()`. Perhaps by subclassing `Tree` and writing a similar function that returns the pointers, would be the solution. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Things have evolved in CGAL, that is you can store other things than just points. Have a look at the [Examples for Using an Arbitrary Point Type with Point Property Maps](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Spatial_searching/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_61.3.6)  in the User Manual.